# Can I use a QGIS geometry in a Python PostGIS query?

Tags: qgis, python, postgis

I have a "Python Init function" for the attribute form in QGIS, which is called when I add a new geometry.

I can access the geometry of the newly created feature like this

```
geom = feature.geometry()
```

Now, can I use this geometry in a PostGIS query, like for ST_Intersects?

Regards,
tkr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to dump it as WKT or WKB and recreate in the query:

```
geometry.exportToWkt()
```

and build the query to build a new geometry from that.